# `MaxEncodedLen` is not implemented for `Vec<u8>`

Tags: substrate-node-template

Here is a simple edit of the `pallet/template/lib.rs` that uses `Vec<u8>` in storage:

```
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]

pub use pallet::*;

#[frame_support::pallet]
pub mod pallet {
    use frame_support::pallet_prelude::*;
    use frame_system::pallet_prelude::*;

    #[pallet::config]
    pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
        type Event: From<Event<Self>> + IsType<<Self as frame_system::Config>::Event>;
    }

    #[pallet::pallet]
    #[pallet::generate_store(pub(super) trait Store)]
    pub struct Pallet<T>(_);

    #[pallet::storage]
    #[pallet::getter(fn something)]
    pub(super) type Something<T: Config> = StorageMap<
        _,
        Twox64Concat,
        T::AccountId,
        Vec<u8>,
        ValueQuery,
    >;

    #[pallet::event]
    #[pallet::generate_deposit(pub(super) fn deposit_event)]
    pub enum Event<T: Config> {
        SomethingStored(Vec<u8>, T::AccountId),
    }

    #[pallet::error]
    pub enum Error<T> {
        NoneValue,
        StorageOverflow,
    }

    #[pallet::call]
    impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
        #[pallet::weight(10_000 + T::DbWeight::get().writes(1))]
        pub fn do_something(origin: OriginFor<T>, something: Vec<u8>) -> DispatchResult {
            let who = ensure_signed(origin)?;
            <Something<T>>::insert(&who, &something);
            Self::deposit_event(Event::SomethingStored(something, who));
            Ok(())
        }
    }
}
```

Using it with the current [substrate-node-template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template) is not compiling due to the following error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Vec<u8>: MaxEncodedLen` is not satisfied
  --> pallets/template/src/lib.rs:15:12
   |
15 |     #[pallet::pallet]
   |               ^^^^^^ the trait `MaxEncodedLen` is not implemented for `Vec<u8>`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `StorageInfoTrait` for `frame_support::pallet_prelude::StorageMap<_GeneratedPrefixForStorageSomething<T>, frame_support::Twox64Concat, <T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId, Vec<u8>, frame_support::pallet_prelude::ValueQuery>`
```

I can compile it using a previous version of the `substrate-node-template` or using the `BoundedVec<u8, T::MaxLength>`, but is there a way to keep using the `Vec<u8>`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`MaxEncodedLen` is all about setting an upper limit to the size of a storage item.

In the case of `Vec<u8>`, there is no limit to the size of this storage, since Vectors in Rust do not have such limits (besides fitting in `usize`).

Thus, if you want to satisfy `MaxEncodedLen`, you must use a `BoundedVec`, and appropriate length limits.

If you want to keep your storage unbounded, you can include `#[pallet::without_storage_info]`.

```
#[pallet::pallet]
#[pallet::generate_store(pub(super) trait Store)]
#[pallet::without_storage_info]
pub struct Pallet<T>(_);
```

This is okay for a solo-chain, but will be incompatible for Parachains since you need to know limits here in order to limit the [PoV size](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/518/what-does-pov-stand-for).

Comment: Thanks Shawn, it makes sense. So I think we need to update: https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/proof-of-existence/#implement-a-storage-map-for-stored-items, right? Will try to do it and open a PR there.

Comment: Yes, will do. Thanks.

Comment: The same issue arises in the kitties tutorial, and it's not with a vec, but with a struct. I'm not sure how to solve it there, except using #[pallet::without_storage_info] — which is definitely only a temporary solution.

Comment: @IlyaS fixed things up here: https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-docs/commit/0f3cca1174244f7eef2bbbf6412e64650e71b369

Comment: I am rewriting my code with `BoundedVec` in structs that are used for storage. While I got an error complaining the trait `Clone` is not implemented for the constant that represents the max length of my `BoundedVec`. It's a runtime config constant of `Get<u32>`, and we may consider expanding the S in `BoundedVec<T, S>` to make it more flexible in this situation.

Comment: Solved my issue with `frame_support::traits::ConstU32`. Reference: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/bc310fdd1040af8a3d2901b5d6f4cf8d5250aeb7/frame/alliance/src/types.rs#L32